# python Question: Could any one explain how the above class reversed the string return val? sorry coming back to python after many years

Tags: python, list, class, slice, return-value

```
class Solution:
  def reverse(self, string):
    if len(string) == 0:
      return string
    else:
      return self.reverse(string[1:]) + string[0]

 a = 'hello'
print Solution().reverse(a)
```

output seems to be 'olleh' but my logic says it should be 'hello' after + string[0] any one knows why?

Comment: It's a recursive function.

Comment: I have no idea how "your logic" works, but it should be very obvious that you can't possibly get back 'hello'. Consider the *first* time that `self.reverse(string[1:]) + string[0]` runs. The `self.reverse(string[1:])` part has to result in *something*, right? And `string[0]` will evaluate to `'h'`, right? And we're going to put that "something" *before* the `'h'`, right? And we aren't putting anything after the `'h'`, right? So...

Comment: string='hello' and string[1:]  = 'ello' + string[0]=h so now we have = elloh if you recurse it one more time then its llohe, then lohel, then ohell, finally hello we end up with the same 'hello'  is what I see from the code how is the result olleh is my question?